# 'str' object is not callable in plotting graph of predicted value

Tags: python, matplotlib, regression

While assigning title using matplotlib.pyplot, an error pops up that 'str' object is not callable. Here is the code, visualising predicted stock prices:

```
plt.title("Predicted Price for next 50 days")
plt.xlabel("Days")
plt.ylabel("Price")
plt.plot(ypred)
```

The following error pops up when the above code is run:

```
<ipython-input-55-cb835b209acc> in <module>
      1 plt.figure(figsize = (12, 6))
----> 2 plt.title("Predicted Price for next 50 days")
      3 plt.xlabel("Days")
      4 plt.ylabel("Price")
      5 plt.plot(ypred)

TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

<Figure size 864x432 with 0 Axes>
```

When I comment lines 1-3, it plots a line graph. Whenever I try to turn any line into code, the above message pops up again.

How do I label the axis and graph?

Comment: Have you used `str =` anywhere?

Comment: Or rather `plt =`

Comment: Yes, I used str & plt to plot the original dataset in the same code.

Comment: Can you upload the entire code please.

Comment: Does the error disappear after you restart your environment?  How did you import `plt`?  Note that you forgot to create a subplot. It might help to call `plt.plot(....)` before `plt.title(....)`